# How to enable popup blocking settings in firefox or chrome using webdriver script?

Tags: popup, webdriver

I tried opening hdfc.com site using Webdriver. It gives a image popup that blocks clicking apply online link. How to handle through the webdriver script? how to enable Block popup windows checkbox in firefox using webdriver scripting?

Answer (score 0):

You should use WindowHandles and ignore the pop-up windows. That way the driver will stay on the original window only .

```
Set<String> handle= driver.getWindowHandles();
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

This way even if you are not able to block the pop-ups , driver will ignore the existence of the other pop-ups and execute the script